# why `location.search` contains `?` and an empty string when no query string part

Tags: javascript

In general, if the url is `https://www.stackoverflow.com?a=1`, `location.search` is `?a=1`

if there's no query string part, the location.search will return an empty string not '?'

why design like so

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#dom-location-search-dev

Comment: You can test this yourself. Enter 'location.search' on the page with no query string and it returns `''`.

Comment: opinion: an empty string is falsy - makes for simpler code logic

Comment: @Bravo yes, it makes sense, falsy is the thing, I just thought it too

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [HTML spec says about `location.search`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#dom-location-search):

> The search getter steps are:

> 1. If `this`'s relevant `Document` is non-`null` and its origin is not same origin-domain with the entry settings object's origin, then throw a `"SecurityError"` `DOMException`.
> 2. **If this's url's query is either `null` or the empty string, return the empty string.**
> 3. Return `"?"`, followed by `this`'s url's query.